# cygwin gcc/g++: "No such file or directory" when including file with an absolute path

Tags: c++, windows, g++, cygwin

g++ gives me an error while trying to compile a minimal file containing a absolute path include when the code file is refered with a path containing '/'. It fails with the following error:

`>g++ ../src/main_b.cpp -o main.exe  ../src/main_b.cpp:5:10: fatal error: D:/training/TestInclude.h: No such file or directory 5 | #include "D:/training/TestInclude.h" |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`

But it doesn't fails when calling the following:

`>g++ ..\src\main_b.cpp -o main.exe`

The failure only occur when the include is present in the cpp file.

CPP File:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "D:/training/TestInclude.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("B - Test\n");
    return 0;
}
```

header file:

```
#ifndef __TEST_INCLUDE_H__
#define __TEST_INCLUDE_H__

#ifndef TEST_DEF
#define TEST_DEF "YOLO"
#endif

#endif
```

G++ version (Provided by Cygwin):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86_64/src/gcc-11.3.0/configure --srcdir=/mnt/share/cygpkgs/gcc/gcc.x86_64/src/gcc-11.3.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --with-gcc-major-version-only --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --enable-libada --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.3.0 (GCC)
```

I'm trying to understand why my compilation fails, to know if it's a compiler error or an unhandled way of refering to a file for the compiler, and to know why the error is so blurry about the issue when just changing the separator resolves the issue. I made a minimal example to show it better.

Comment: Inside Cygwin, your drive letters are mapped to unix-like paths. Citing from head, `D:` should become `/cygdrive/d/`. Give that a try. This also nicely illustrates the pitfalls of using absolute paths.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't use absolute paths in includes.

Comment: I agree with HolyBlackCat, but I encountered this issue with generated code.

Comment: It does work in both cases with the path `/cygdrive/d/` but it doesn't explains the difference I'm having with the way I call the compiler with the Windows formatted include path `D:/`.

Comment: Another option is to not use Cygwin. E.g. [MSYS2 compilers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) shouldn't have this problem.